# Javamail using Exchange as relay

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2010, jboss, smtp-auth

I have to fix an "unable to relay". The java server has to send emails to the internet. The java server and the exchange server are in the same network.
How I configure properly a receive connector in exchange server 2010 to avoid as it is in the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291412/send-email-in-java-via-relay-server . It's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681703/how-to-send-an-email-using-ms-exchange-server but I am caring about security and spam.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Receive Connector for the Java Server. Restrict the connection settings to allow only that IP address to connect.
Then grant anonymous relaying permissions to that new receive connector.

As long as you put the correct restrictions in for connection it cannot be abused.